# React native shared preferences null is not an object on calling SetPreferences

Tags: react-native

I am learning to react native in Expo and I am trying to use shared preferences.
Is this problem with the package or my code?

this is my code:

```
var SharedPreferences = require("react-native-shared-preferences");

updatePref = () => {
  SharedPreferences.setItem("test", 15);
};
loadPref = () => {
  SharedPreferences.getItem("test", function (value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
};
createPref = () => {
  SharedPreferences.setName("tuta");
};

const Pocetna = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={updatePref}>
        <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>0</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={updatePref}>
        <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>0</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.createPref}>
        <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>create</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={updatePref}>
        <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>set</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={loadPref}>
        <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>print</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

And i get error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'SharedPreferences.setName')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Configure name of preferences file.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shared-preferences#configure-name-of-preferences-file-optional-must-be-called-before-other-functions) (**Optional. Must be called before other functions.**)

```
SharedPreferences.setName("tuta"); // need to be called initially
```